# How can I force to crash a command with 's' permission in linux?

Tags: linux, coredump

I want to read core dump of a `s` permission command and analyze it. So I need an approach to make crash these commands. For example, how can I make `passwd` or `su` crash and create a core dump? Using `^\` won't work for these commands.

Comment: `core dump of s permission command`? What command? What is `s` permission? What is `s` permission command? You mean setuid __bit__? You want to crash these command _how_? Crash dump is generated by the operating system, not by any command. You can generate core dump of a program by attaching a debugger to it. You shouldn't be able to "crash"/break `passwd` nor `su`, at least not easy, they are written that way so they are safe. What's with `^\`, what's it's supposed to mean and how did you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending the process a SIGSEGV signal as root:

```
~ # pidof passwd
12840
~ # kill -SIGSEGV 12840
~ #
```

Result:

```
~ # ls -l /sbin/passwd
-rwsr-sr-x    1 root     root        908672 Nov  8 18:28 /sbin/passwd
~ # ulimit -c 100000
~ # /sbin/passwd
Changing password for root
New password: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
/ #
```